# How to validate token issued by Azure Active Directory with Wildfly 11's Elytron subsystem?

Tags: azure-active-directory, bearer-token, wildfly-11

I'm trying to protect the application's REST API hosted in my Wildfly 11 container with BEARER_TOKEN that is issued by Azure Active Directory.

What I've done already:

1. Migrated from Legacy security to Elytron security.
2. Created a token realm
3. Registered an application at AAD.

I can't find a way to configure AAD's public keys URL.
Is there a configuration I can set to point to the public keys at https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys ?
How the Application Server suppose to validate the tokens that AAD issues?

Comment: Can you provide a link to a general example how this integration works? I am interested in such a solution and I wonder if it is necessary to implement a SSO/SAML module by my self?